# Eclipse CDT PTP Remote Tools will remotely build makefile, but not make/compile after

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-rse

I am trying to use Eclipse 4.3 on Windows for remote Linux C++ development. I am currently using the Eclipse PTP package which comes with all the necessary plugins to do remote development. I made a new C++ Remote Project and I have it set to talk to the linux machine via the 'Remote Tools' service. I am able to use all the terminal and file browsing services as expected. However, when I go to 'build' my project, all it does is generate the makefile on the remote machine, it will not compile it into a binary. Through terminal, I can make the makefile and it will compile be run successfully. However, the generated binary is not seen by eclipse and so all the nice binary things like Run/Debug can not be used on the manually made binary.

Essentially I am looking for a way to hit the 'Build' button, and have it compile my remote project into a binary that will be recognized by eclipse.